# Does Pandas support quarterly dates of the form yyyyQp (e.g. 2013Q2)?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm importing a CSV of macroeconomic data and haven't been able to figure out how to get Pandas to interpret this type of date. Is there a way to do it automatically or will I need to parse it myself?

When I ask the parser to try, I get:

```
  File "datetime.pxd", line 133, in datetime._string_to_dts (pandas/tslib.c:31399)ValueError: Unable to parse 2002Q1
```

Comment: The period class will accept this format and understand it, but it doesn't seem to recognize it when importing from a CSV into a dataframe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the `pd.Period` can parse quarterly periods, you could use it as the custom `date_parser`. Then, to convert the date to the last day of the quarter, you could use `map` and the `end_time` attribute:

```
import pandas as pd

text = '''\
date    val
2013Q2 100
2013Q3 120
'''

filename = '/tmp/data'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
df = pd.read_table(filename, sep='\s+', date_parser=pd.Period, parse_dates=[0])
df['date'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: x.end_time.date())

print(df)
#          date  val
# 0  2013-06-30  100
# 1  2013-09-30  120
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to help those who have years and quarters in different columns:

```
year quarter foo
1994 q1      10
1994 q3      20
1995 q1      30
1995 q3      40
```

The `parse_dates` argument to `read_csv` just works. It's very cool:

```
>>> pd.read_csv('bar.csv', parse_dates={'period':['year', 'quarter']})
period       foo
1994 q1      10
1994 q3      20
1995 q1      30
1995 q3      40
```

Answer (score 0):

It has very nice support for all the various business dates/times and frequencies. But you will probably have to parse that particular format yourself.